# Illustrator - Substract text from shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I'm using Illustrator CS6 to substract text from a shape. I tried **Create Outlines** after typing my text, then using **Minus** from **Pathfinder** to substract it from the shape. But then I get this result:

[image]

Please tell me why it get distorted like that. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "bake in" the `Round Corners Effect` before using Pathfinder.

Select the rectangle, and choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu... Then use Pathfinder to subtract the text.

The issue is that the round corners effect is being applied to the counters (holes) created by the text as well as the outside corners. By expanding the appearance of the rectangle you remove the "effect" and leave the results the effect was achieving.